# 'Key does not exist.' when signing

Tags: c#, network-programming, rsa

i`m working on a test for signing and verifying signatures, and instead of it signing and sending it just throws an error, here are both the signing code (not including server verification as it is irrelevant and too long) and the key swapping code.

Here is the server:

```cs
            // variables
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[8192];
            // initialize network stream
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            // send length of public key
            networkStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey()).Length.ToString()));
            // send public key
            networkStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey())));
            // read public key length
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom);
            // apply public key length
            bytesFrom = new byte[int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom))];
            // read public key
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom);
            // import public key
            int a;
            rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(rsa.Decrypt(bytesFrom, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512), out a);
```

Here is the client:

```cs
                // initialize RSA and connect
                RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
                IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 500);
                Socket sock = new Socket(end.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sock.Connect(end);
                NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(sock);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                // read public key length
                ns.Read(buffer);
                // apply public key length
                buffer = new byte[int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer))];
                // read public key
                ns.Read(buffer);
                // apply public key
                int a;
                rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(buffer, out a);
                // send public key length and public key 
                ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey().Length.ToString()));
                ns.Write(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey());
                // send signed "h"
                ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("h"), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1).Length.ToString()));
                ns.Write(rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("h"), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out that all i need is to just dump the private key temporarily while i switch keys then import it back in the end.